# How to create a dynamic table view in android

Tags: android

I used the concept for this:
(1.) Creating a custom listview and the code is below:

custom_row_view :

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
>    <!--  android:background="#801A1A1A" > -->
>
>     <TableRow
>         android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:background="#000000"
>         android:padding="1dp">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/textView1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:padding="2dp"
>             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:textSize="10dp"
>             android:background="#FFFFFF"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/myTextviewText"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/textView2"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="2"
>             android:padding="2dp"
>             android:textSize="10dp"
>             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:background="#FFFFFF"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/myTextviewText"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/textView3"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:padding="2dp"
>             android:textSize="10dp"
>             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:background="#FFFFFF"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/myTextviewText"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/textView4"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight=".5"
>             android:padding="2dp"
>             android:textSize="10dp"
>             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:background="#FFFFFF"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/myTextviewText"
>             android:text="TextView" />
>
>     </TableRow>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

I got a problem when I using the above procedure, i use weight property in the row custom view, yet the textview stretched according to the text size.
the problem is :
[image]

Comment: Set the `layout_width` of your TextView's in a row to `0dp` and use layout_weight (as you already do).  I think it should sort you out.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir, its working fine... its really a great approach